# Only the lowest branches of my Pine tree is turning brown and their needles are falling off: why it happened and how to avoid it

Tags: trees, diagnosis, pines

More than a month ago, I bought some kind of Pine tree. At the time, the all the branches and needle leaves were fine:

[image: When I bought]

The seller told me to water it twice a week. I did so. I keep the tree inside, next to the kitchen. The tree is *not* exposed to direct sunlight, it gets light indirectly.

But now, ***only*** the lowest branches are turning brown and their needle leaves are falling off.

[image: Brown branches]

What kind of Pine tree is my tree? How can I keep it healthy? I studied [this post](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/5395/15914), but just thought I'd ask anyway, maybe pictures would help with diagnosis. Thanks!

Comment: We have one and it does well in a bright cool north facing window.  See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Araucaria_heterophylla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like a Norfolk Island Pine. [Here](https://www.pennington.com/all-products/fertilizer/resources/nurturing-norfolk-island-pines-year-round) is a pretty good article on their care.

There's a good chart of problems and treatments. To summarize:

- Drooping leaves, needles, or tips: Gradually move tree to get more light.
- Drooping branches at trunk: Water more frequently or thoroughly
- Overly dark needles: Gradually move tree to get more light.
- Yellowing needles: Water less often, empty saucer
- Brown needles: Increase humidity, keep from cold drafts and temps below 50F
- Branch loss: Gradually increase water/light.