# Is humic acid good for Norfolk Island Pine tree

Tags: trees, fertilizer, pines

I have a Norfolk Island Pine tree discussed [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/55412/15914). I want to improve its well-being. Would liquid humic acid be helpful? What kind of fertilizer would be most effective? Is there any related documentation to study?

[image: Norfolk Island Pine tree]

[image: humic acid]

Answer (score 1):

I find Norfolk Island Pines grow too big for a house plant in a few years with only  minimal ordinary fertilizer so I would do nothing to increase growth.